# Dropdown Element is invisible using Selenium TestNG

Tags: selenium

The dropdown element is invisible but it is enable and present.

I have tried everything but I am out of options. Please help. My goal is to click that dropdown that will show a textfield to input a string.

Code snippet:

```
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']"))!= null){
        System.out.println("Element is Present");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Element is Absent");
    }

    if( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']")).isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println("Element is Visible");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
    }

    if( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']")).isEnabled()){
        System.out.println("Element is Enable");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Element is Disabled");
    }
```

Output:

Element is Present
Element is InVisible
Element is Enable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUH9v.jpg)

Comment: have you tried waiting for the page to completely load? the parent div has the following attribute: `data-bind="visible: CanSelectBroker() && !IsLoadingBrokers()"` what are the values of those functions? might have something to do with it.

Comment: Can you replace `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']"))!= null` with `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']")).size()!= 0` in your first **if** statement and share the output?

Comment: Mahipal, the output is still Element is Present

Comment: becixb, i've increased the wait time and it did the trick. thanks!

Comment: it worked earlier then now it is not working again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Webdriver wait until the visibility of the required drop down and then click on it. Try following and let me know, whether it resolves your issue:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen3']")));
```

In the above code, Webdriver will wait for a maximum of 60 seconds for the required drop down to become visible. If even after 60 seconds the drop down is not visible, it will fail with a timeout error.

Comment: Great. You are welcome. Could you accept my answer and mark it as useful, if it was useful and resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Mahipal has to work. Other reason might be the Frame. Make sure that dropdown is not inside an Frame.

Comment: it should be comment

Comment: Thanks Narendra.. btw i just started answering stackoverflow. I will follow the same going forward.